# ConcurrentModificationException: When update spring data jpa parent entity

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jhipster

I have two jpa entities: Family and FamilyMembers.

Family:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "family")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Family implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "family")
    private Set<FamilyMember> familyMembers = new HashSet<>();
}
```

FamilyMember

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "family_member")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class FamilyMember implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name="family_id")
    private Family family;
}
```

The family entity is the parent entity of family members.

My problem came on when I try to update the parent entity "family" using the below code:

```
familyRepository.save(family);
```

I got the below exception:

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException:
```

Please advise!

Comment: Please add the full stack trace

Comment: You can add cascade = CascadeType.ALL to you parent entity, so the child entityes will be saved too with it

Comment: Many thanks, guys. I have solved the issue. Please look to below details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem.

I was calling below method within the same transaction:

```
    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Optional<EntityAuditConfiguration> findByEntityName(String entityName) {
        return entityAuditConfigurationRepository.findByEntityName(entityName);
    }
```

I changed the method to create a new spring transaction as follows:

```
    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public Optional<EntityAuditConfiguration> findByEntityName(String entityName) {
        return entityAuditConfigurationRepository.findByEntityName(entityName);
    }
```